# Is there any way to customize 'Access denied' Message in dynamcis 365

Tags: dynamics-365, access-denied

when a user(user has BU level READ permission) changes the owner of his record to another user in a different business unit, he is loosing his access to that record and  getting access denied message. Is there any way we can customize the message to make it more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

However, you could build customization that displays your own message (which I don't believe will stop the OOB one from showing) or a confirmation message, where you let the user know what will happen if they change ownership of the record.